# Node js raw query returns anonymous datatype

Tags: node.js, loopback

I am new to node and loopback, I wanted to execute a raw query with call back and I am getting result as well in anonymous form
My query is  :

```
        query = `select u.modelid from ${ schema }.dayjob as u where jobid = 1 and createdat::date > '2019-11-15' and createdat::date < '2019-11-22' ;`
```

for which I am getting ***[ anonymous { modelid: 177 } ]*** as output

Is there any specific way to get rid of 'anonymous' ?

Comment: Where are you seeing `[ anonymous { modelid: 177 } ]`? Are you using `console.log` to inspect the result of the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**anonymous** in loopback represents the model you are querying is anonymous. The model defined by loopback for RawQueries.

It would display if you console.log the query result directly but not exposed when you convert to json. Try logging it by converting to JSON

```
results.forEach(function(result) {
   var res = result.toJSON();
   console.log(res);
 });
```